# crawler to grab chrome extension id's

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-crawler

How would I come about writing a crawler for the Google chrome extensions website? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

I am doing a little security research on chrome extensions. About 100 extensions per category and the problem I am having right now is writing a crawler to at least grab the UID's. The website appears to be updated by javascript. If I were to grab the html, I'd get nothing because the site appears to load the rest of the page at a later stage. In other words, the core content I need (i.e. the DOM with all the extension elements) seems to load after I grab the HTML using python. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the webpage doesn't contain the data - it is downloaded separately. A URL like this one is used:

> `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/item?pv=1389738107&count=100&category=app/7-productivity`

Note that this has to be a POST request (without any POST data), other requests will be rejected for security reasons. You have to remove `")]}'"` at the beginning of the file and `"[]\n"` in various other places - then you should get proper JSON that can be parsed via `json.loads`. The data isn't very structured but should be good enough for crawling.

Note that the `pv` parameter looks like it might change soon (this Unix time corresponds to a date four days ago), you can use the Network tab of Chrome's Developer Tools to see the current request parameters. The `category` parameter is the identifier of the category - it's the URL part after `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/` in Web Store links.

Comment: @IvanThai: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @WladimirWell; +1 This question certainly seems to help me a lot! I am working on the same thing. However, when I fire the request for the given URL, I get a response saying "An error has occured". Do I need to send something else along with my request? Any help appreciated.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: Did you send a POST request? There were no real changes to the way the Web Store works, merely the category identifiers are different now and the `pv` parameter has a new value (as I noted in the post, this one likely changes every few days). I updated the answer with the current URL parameters.

Comment: Yes, I did it. But I got a "Bad Request" message. I also tried downloading the extensions using the `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/item` URL. (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255328/crawler-to-grab-chrome-extension-ids)) but I get a XMLHttpError message.

Comment: Also, I when I made a request to Chrome Web Store using Scrapy shell, I just get the left hand side column as a response and not the whole page.