# How do I get the IDs of Chrome extensions programatically from the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: python, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, python-requests

My question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255328/crawler-to-grab-chrome-extension-ids), in that I am trying to download Chrome extensions programatically. My initial thoughts were along the same line as the linked question and I was thinking of wrinting a program for crawling (using Scrapy). However, I noticed that the page is dynamic, the crawler just downloads the HTML frame and that the browser makes a request to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/item` to download the JSON for extensions (which also contain the extension ID). So, I tried to create a POST request using the `Requests` library of Python. I tried to make a request using the values (of payload and cookies) sent by my browser (as follows):

```
>>>url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/item"
>>>cookies = dict(NID='67=R4qURXDfck7w88_e3h9K7nlH3p5P0DVYSsv6H48ItU4ySyEteOzBmCJeOeyIGpufjsPq8nXq3g6X9spvFtUnBi41nFFkL9hKCOkGNNya6YkdfMrbP6gbTcCxwL2SXlyq', __utma='73091649.1313886221.1389991622.1390001718.1390050575.3', __utmb='73091649.17.9.1390051810097', __utmc='73091649', __utmz='73091649.1389991622.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)')
>>>payload = {'hl': 'en-US', 'gl': 'US', 'pv': '138978106', 'mce': 'c3d,ncr,ctm,ac,hot,emc,apl,grt,spa,spb,shr','count': '0','token': '151@461735', 'category': 'extensions', 'sortBy': '0', 'container': 'CHROME', '_reqid': '5129379','rt': 'j'}
>>>r = requests.post(url, params=payload, cookies=cookies)
```

However, when I get send this request, I get the response:

```
>>> r.text
u')]}\'\n\n[[["er",,,,["xhrerrorresponse",1]\n,400,"xhrerrorresponse",,,9]\n,["e",2,,,102]\n]]'
```

I don't know what is causing this XMLHttpRequest Error. Can anyone tell how do I fix this? Or download the IDs of Chrome extensions in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Chrome Web Store does not expose an API to do what you are asking.